# how do i use regex to get a string inside two character and remove certain characters inside that string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a long string that I want to filter using regex

```
<@961483653468439706> Text to remove, this text is useless, that's why i want it gone!
i want this: `keep the letters and spaces`
```

I want to keep the text that in-between the ` characters

only issue is that in-between every character in the part of the string I want there is an invisible character.
you can see the invisible characters in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/rAYrMT/1

```
`([\'^\w]*)`
```

So in short: keep everything between ` except for the invisible characters info on which can be found here: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BF

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: How is the string obtained?  It sounds like it's been wrongly decoded, in which case decoding it properly would probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the non printable characters out:

```
import re 
from string import printable

# your invisibles are in the string...

s='''<@961483653468439706> Text to remove, this text is useless, that's why i want it gone!
Type `keep the letters and spaces` and `this too`'''

for m in re.findall(r'`([^`]*)`', s):
    print(repr(m))
    print(''.join([c for c in m if c in printable]))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
'k\ufeffe\ufeffe\ufeffp\ufeff \ufefft\ufeffh\ufeffe\ufeff \ufeffl\ufeffe\ufefft\ufefft\ufeffe\ufeffr\ufeffs a\ufeffn\ufeffd s\ufeffp\ufeffa\ufeffc\ufeffe\ufeffs'
keep the letters and spaces

'this too'
this too
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this:

```
text = "<@961483653468439706> Text to remove, this text is useless, that's " \
       "why i want it gone!Type `k﻿e﻿e﻿p﻿ ﻿t﻿h﻿e﻿ ﻿l﻿e﻿t﻿t﻿e﻿r﻿s a﻿n﻿d s﻿p﻿a﻿c﻿e﻿s`"

# put your invisible character between the first quotation marks here. obviously, they
# don't show up in this post.
filtered = text.replace('﻿', '')
# because the passage you want is always between ``, you can split it and know that every
# second item in the list that split returns must be what you are looking for. 
passage = filtered.split('`')[::2]

print(passage)
```